# Subversion FS API

Tags: svn, fsfs

We are considering to use Subversion as the file system layer to store version enabled documents. Since the security function will be handled by other code, I am considering to directly use the Subversion FS C API layer. I wonder if there any good sample code for using Subversion FS APIs?

Answer (score 0):

Subversion's FSFS store is meant to be used by the subversion server.  While it might be useable in other scenarios, whatever sits on top of it will likely have to act much like a subversion server when interacting with it.

Subversion differentiates between client workspaces and the server storage space.  If you are going to leverage subversion components, your application needs to realize that these two spaces are not the same within a subversion architecture, and therefore should not be the same within your solution that uses their components.

Why not just embed a subversion client into the place you desire and then go from there?  The user workspace will still be "the subversion user workspace" and the server side will be the server side.

In fact, check out tortise SVN (or other desktop integrations of subversion).  You might not even need to write anything.

Comment: SVN Client API will have performance penalty since it will go through other layers such as user authentications, authorizations, transport etc. which are not needed for us. Subversion server side API will bypass those calls. I wonder which API mod_dav_svn used.

Comment: mod_dav_svn is far slower than svnserve  it is webdav protocol, which is layered on top of HTTP protocol, with the "SVN" stuff wrapped deep in the middle.